# cv sending in email using wp-mail

Tags: php, wordpress

I have uploaded a cv successfully from a career page . Now i want to send this in email.

**Upload part**

```
 if ($_FILES['filecv']['name'] != "") {
        $sqldata['att_ment'] = uploadCVFile($_FILES['filecv']);
    } else {
        $sqldata['att_ment'] = '';
    }
```

CV is uploaded successfully.

**uploadCVFile function**

```
 function uploadCVFile($uploadedfile)
 {
    if (!function_exists('wp_handle_upload'))
    require_once (ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    $upload_overrides = array('test_form' => false);
    add_filter('upload_dir', 'cv_uploads_dir');
    $movefile = wp_handle_upload($uploadedfile, $upload_overrides);
    remove_filter('upload_dir', 'cv_uploads_dir');
    if ($movefile) {
        return basename($movefile['file']); //$uploadedfile['name'];
    } else {
         return "";
    }
   }
```

**path set**

```
  function cv_uploads_dir($param)
  {
    $param['subdir'] = '/cvs';
    $param['path'] = $param['basedir'] . $param['subdir'];
    $param['url'] = $param['baseurl'] . $param['subdir'];
    return $param;
  }
```

now i want to send this in email using the wp_mail function. all other data is sent successfully but i dont know how to deal with the cv.

**Mail function**

```
 function SendCareers_Email($pst)
{
$to = get_option('career_email');
$from = $pst['e-mail'];
$name = $pst['firstname'];
$cvname="/uploads/cvs/".$sqldata['att_ment'];
$subject = "Applying for the job " . $pst['title'];
$message= "Candidate Name:-" . $name . "<br/>";
$message .= "Job Title Applied:-" . $pst['title'] . "<br/>";
if(!empty($pst['country'])){
$message .= "Country Of Resindency:-" . $pst['country'] . "<br/>";
}
if(!empty($pst['nationlaity'])){
$message .= "Nationlaity:-" . $pst['nationlaity'] . "<br/>";
}
$attachments = array( WP_CONTENT_DIR . $cvname );
if(!empty($pst['mobileno'])){
$message .= "Phone Number:-" . $pst['mobileno'] . "<br/>";
}
add_filter('wp_mail_content_type', 'set_career_html_content_type');
$admin_headers = 'From: '.$name.' <'.$from .'>' . "\r\n\\";
wp_mail($to, $subject,$message ,  $admin_headers,$attachments);
remove_filter('wp_mail_content_type', 'set_career_html_content_type'); 
}
function set_career_html_content_type()
{
    return 'text/html';
}
```

Comment: $cvname="/uploads/cvs/".$sqldata['att_ment']; you need to pass $sqldata into the function. It's not available yet. Or use $_FILES['filecv']['name'] instead of $sqldata['att_ment']

Comment: $_FILES['filecv']['name'] i have used this. its not sending the attachemtn

Comment: That is what I call spaghetti code, can you make your mind about the naming convention? Either way it looks like you never get into the uploadCVFiles method since `$sqldata['att_ment']` do not exist

Comment: If you've made more changes, please update the function again. Currently you aren't using the correct value in your code

Comment: it worked @Brett . thanks alloot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SendCareersEmail function change this part

```
$cvname="/uploads/cvs/".$_FILES['filecv']['name'];

$attachments = array(
     $cvname
);
```

When inside a function only global variables or variables you pass into the function (in your case $pst) are available. So either pass in $sqldata to the function SendCVEmail($pst, $sqldata) or use the global call of $_FILES['filecv']['name']

Comment: i have removed this. this was not working .inplace of this i have used this  $attachments = array( WP_CONTENT_DIR . $cvname );

Comment: $cvname="/uploads/cvs/".$_FILES['filecv']['name'];

Comment: Can you update your question with the new code changes?

Comment: now when i give name of specific file that is present in cvs folder then it is send. but the uplaoded file name is not getting here

Comment: And you are definitely sure that the file is at that path?

Comment: yes i am sure because i have checked it with a static file name